# How to find a namespace of base class via Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'am writing source generator that makes a copy (with some little changes) of simple DTO classes. I have copied all contained properties and all works fine. But some of my classes inherited from another like this:

```cs
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I can't just copy inheritance declaration, because my copied classes locaded in different namespace. So I need to add `using` to namespace of `MyBaseClass`, so I need to find than namespace. I've already done this for my property types using semantic model, like this:

```cs
Compilation
   .GetSemanticModel(propertyNode.Type.SyntaxTree)
   .GetSymbolInfo(propertyNode.Type)
   .Symbol
   .ContainingNamespace
```

But I have unexpected issue with gettting namespace from base type. What i've tried for now:

```cs
// list of all base types
var typeList = classNode.BaseList;                  
var semanticModel = Compilation.GetSemanticModel(typeList.SyntaxTree);

var symbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(typeList); // symbol.Symbol is null
var type = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(typeList);     // type.Type is null
```

```cs
// list of all base types
var firstType = classNode.BaseList.Types[0]; 
var semanticModel = Compilation.GetSemanticModel(firstType.SyntaxTree);

var symbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(firstType); // symbol.Symbol is null
var type = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(firstType);     // type.Type is null
```

```cs
// list of all base types
var typeList = classNode.BaseList;
var semanticModel = Compilation.GetSemanticModel(typeList.SyntaxTree);

var symbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(typeList.Types[0]); // symbol.Symbol is null
var type = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(typeList.Types[0]);     // type.Type is null
```

I dont know what went wrong. I've tried to call different methods with different parameters, but did not get proper result. May be there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(typeList.Types[0].Type)
```

(note the extra ".Type" in there)